# Extracting a set from a list of composite elements in python

Tags: python

I'm maintaining `message_id` and `message_writer_id` together in a python list like so:

```
composite_items = ['1:2', '2:2', '3:2', '4:1', '5:19', '20:2', '45:1', ...]
```

Where each element is `message_id:message_poster_id`.

From the above list, I want to extract the `set` of all `message_writer_ids`. I.e. I want to extract a `set` containing all unique numbers *after* `:` so that I end up with:

```
item_set = ['2', '1', '19']
```

What's the most efficient way to do that in python?

---

Currently, I'm thinking I'll do something like:

```
new_list = []
for item in composite_items:
    element = item.split(":")[1]
    new_list.append(element)
new_set = set(new_list)
```

Was wondering if there's  a faster way to achieve this.

Comment: More consise, may be slightly faster. Let's pass generator comprehension to constructor of `set`:  `set(o.split(':')[1] for o in composite_items)`

Comment: Fair enough, it's an improvement. I'll accept this as an answer if you post it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use set comprehension like so:

```
new_set = {item.partition(":")[2] for item in composite_items}
```

Set comprehension is fast, and unlike `str.split()`, `str.partition()` splits only once and stops looking for more colons. Quite the same as with `str.split(maxsplit=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
composite_items = ['1:2', '2:2', '3:2', '4:1', '5:19', '20:2', '45:1', ...]
posters = dict()
for element in composite_items:
    poster_id = element.split(":")[1]
    posters[poster_id] = posters.get(poster_id, 0) + 1
```

You can use dictionaries and also count how many messages sent by `message_poster_id`. `posters.get(poster_id,0) + 1` checks that a poster exists or not. If exists it gets its value (number of messages) and increment it by 1.

If doesn't exist its add the poster_id to dictionary and sets it to 0.